# Border line in computer folder

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I know this question is easy for you but I have a lot of problem with it. 
Hope you could help me out.
As you can see in the picture below, what does the vertical line (in red box) is called?
And how can I move cursor quickly to select that line so I can enlarge or narrow the column?

Border line in computer folder:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's called a 'splitter' or pane splitter, Window splitter or splitter bar.  You move your mouse on it to resize it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a fast way to do that? I ask this because to select the spliter, I have to adjust the cursor several times. It is really irritating.

Comment: I don't think there's any way of moving it with the keyboard. You can save the size of those windows once set though, if that's what you want.  You can also remove the 'library' pane if that's not needed.